# Is it possible in OpenAI gym to persist the state as hidden and only make some variables visible to the players?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to create a game in which there is a lead time in the actions of the player and the rewards/consequences, therefore, I would like to not share the observation completely with the player, but still persist it because it's need for future. Is there a way we can do that?
If I create a variable in init and update it, it's visible to every instance of the game, so a player already knows a lot more than I'd have them know.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to exactly get? An example environment pseudocode maybe?

Comment: So I want to create a game in which the consequences of an action has a delay of 2 days, the reinforcement learning cycle is:
1. make decision #1
2. get observations #1 (effect of decision #1 has not come into place)
3. make decision #2
4. get observations #1 (effect of neither decision #1 or #2 has come into place)
3. make decision #3
4. get observations (effect of decision #1 apparent)
5. make decision #4
6. get observations (effect of decision #2 also apparent)
...

Answer (score 0):

A rough example for your requirement on Cartpole would be something like this:

```py
import gym
from gym.utils import seeding
import numpy as np


class myEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Define all the necessary stuff here
        """
        self.env = gym.make('CartPole-v1') # add stuff here to define game params
        self.action_space = self.env.action_space
        self.observation_space = self.env.observation_space
        self.past_actions = []
        self.delay = 2  # to have a delay of two timesteps

    def reset(self):
        """
            Define the reset
        """
        self.observation = self.env.reset()
        return self.observation

    def step(self, action):
        """
            Add the delay of actions here
        """
        self.past_actions.append(action)    # to keep track of actions
        reward = 0; done = 0; info = {}     # reward, done and info are 0,0,{} for first two timesteps
        if len(self.past_actions) > self.delay:
            present_action = self.past_actions.pop(0)
            # change observation, reward, done, info 
            # according to the action 'delay' timesteps ago
            self.observation, reward, done, info = self.env.step(present_action)
        return self.observation, reward, done, info

    def seed(self, seed=0):
        """
            Define seed method here
        """
        self.np_random, seed = seeding.np_random(seed)
        return self.env.seed(seed=seed)

    def render(self, mode="human", *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Define rendering method here
        """
        return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def close(self):
        """
            Define close method here
        """
        return self.env.close()
```